# Disable initial command name autocompletion Git Bash

Tags: bash, autocomplete, git-bash

When I have a blank prompt, if I press tab then the console freezes while it gets all available commands that start with "". Is there a way to disable this? I still want to have autocompletion when typing files, but Bash seems to search PATH for all files in every directory. I know this because if I press tab twice and wait for about ~5 minutes, I get a "Display all 4487 possibilities? (y/n) " prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-E` of `complete` :

```
empty_command_completion(){ :; }
complete -E -F empty_command_completion
```

Comment: Where would this go? In `~/.bashrc` or the git bash equivalent?

Comment: Never mind, it goes in `/etc/bash.bashrc` and it works. Thanks!

Comment: It's better to put in `~/.bashrc`, instead of system-wide `/etc/bash.bashrc`

Comment: Great answer! How can we modify this so it also considers the case when there is only whitespace in the prompt ?

Comment: @Bunder I tried a couple of things but didn't manage to achieve what you wanted to do, maybe you can raise a new question.